# Java beginner here getting non zero numbers

Tags: java

I just want to ask why the `temp` in my method `NonZeros` does not change its elements even though I explicitly assign each element of `temp` whenever the source has a nonzero element. Here's my work.

```
package nonzeros;
public class NonZeros {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] B = {0,1,2,3,2};
        int [] newone = NonZeros(B);
        for(int q = 0; q < newone.length; q++){
            System.out.println(newone[q]);
        }
    }
    public static int[] NonZeros(int [] A){
        int [] temp = new int[4];
        for(int i = 0; i < A.length;i++){
            if(A[i] != 0){
                int j = 0;
                temp[j] = A[i];
                j++;
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }
}
```

Here's the result:
run:
2
0
0
0

However, the result should be: 1 2 3 2

Comment: `int j = 0;`  what do you expect this to do to `temp[j]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step one, count the non zero values. Step two, create the new array. Step three, fill it with non-zero values like

```
public static int[] NonZeros(int[] A) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        if (A[i] != 0) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    int[] temp = new int[count];
    int p = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        if (A[i] != 0) {
            temp[p++] = A[i];
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Alternatively, use a lambda and filter like

```
public static int[] NonZeros(int[] A) {
    return Arrays.stream(A).filter(i -> i != 0).toArray();
}
```

Comment: I think that using lambda expressions and streams is a bit too advanced for a beginner.

Comment: @IslamEl-Rougy Never too early to expose advanced concepts. Notice I started with a more classic implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You declare `int j=0;` *inside* the loop, so all assignments go to the same place.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the `j` index outside of the loop:

```
public static int[] NonZeros(int [] A){
    int [] temp = new int[4];
    int j = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < A.length; i++) {
        if (A[i] != 0) {
            temp[j] = A[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

The reason why your current output happens to be `[2, 0, 0, 0]` is that the final element in the input array is 2, and gets written to the first entry in the output array.  In fact, currently *all* values are being written to the first entry of the output array.

Comment: Thank you! and by the way, is there a library member function in java that acts like a push_back in vector C++ but works only on built-in arrays?

Comment: I don't know C++ or Boost very well.  Check Elliot's answer for a way to do this using Lambdas.

Comment: @Elo: Arrays are fixed-size, so `push_back` wouldn’t make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

The scope of the "j" variable that you are defining is the if block that contains it because you are declaring it inside the condition which results in you overwriting the first element in your temp array each time you find a non-zero number in the source while the rest of your temp elements remain unchanged.
The solution is to move the declaration of "j" to the body of the method just before the loop, that is:

```
public static int[] NonZeros(int [] A){
int [] temp = new int[4];
int j = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < A.length;i++){
    if(A[i] != 0){
        temp[j] = A[i];
        j++;
    }
}
return temp;
}
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen When I started typing the answer, there were no answers to the question. I will delete the answer if you wish anyway.

Comment: No worries...the notification system seems perpetually broken.